# Should TypeScript guarantee functions' return value?

Tags: typescript

I have the following simple function which takes any type of argument and is supposed to return a number:

```
function foo(x:any): number {
    return x.bar;
}

var b = {bar: "shit happens"};
console.log(foo(b)); // foo returns 'shit happens' which is not a number.
```

It seems that if x.bar does not contain a number then this function's return value can be anything.

My question is: Is there a way to guarantee that the function's return value will always be a number and nothing else (like in other strongly typed languages)? If not, then what's the advantage of using TypeScript if the typing system only gives a "hint" of the preferable return types that should be used and permits incorrect return types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is your use of the `any` type.
Basically you're telling the compiler "look, I know what I'm doing, don't check things for me".
You should avoid using `any` because then you bypass the compiler checks, and if you're going to do that, then why not just use javascript?

If you won't use `any` but a type or interface then you'll get an error:

```
type FooParam = {
    bar: number;
}

function foo(x: FooParam): number {
    return x.bar;
}

var b = { bar: "shit happens" };
console.log(foo(b));
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20FooParam%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09bar%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20foo(x%3A%20FooParam)%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20x.bar%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20b%20%3D%20%7B%20bar%3A%20%22shit%20happens%22%20%7D%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(foo(b))%3B))

You'll get an error in the last line:

> Argument of type `{ bar: string; }` is not assignable to parameter of
>   type `{ bar: number; }`

You can avoid having this `FooParam` type:

```
function foo(x: { bar: number }): number { ... }
```